# I cannot ping domain under the same server but can from other machine

Tags: ubuntu, server

My web server arch is  `cloudflare CDN ----> Nginx ---> Web`

For example , the web domain is www.weba.com.
I can access the weba from my local machine

```
curl www.weba.com  -> get response
```

However, when I ssh in to weba then type in the terminal

```
curl www.weba.com ->  url: (7) Failed to connect to www.weba.com port 80: Connection refused
ping www.weba.com -> get response!
traceroute www.weba.com -> get response and show only one step.
```

How can I get more detail or solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting locally via the ip & localhost from the target host's terminal:

```
curl -i http://localhost:80
telnet localhost 80
```

If you do not get rejected, this looks like a firewall issue.
Check iptables to see if theres any explicit rules which would prevent your local host from accessing port 80 (I am assuming thats your webserver):

```
iptables -L
```

If you DO get rejected it seems that nginx is the culprit. Check your nginx config and error logs for anything related to your error. I do not think nginx is the cause because the "Connection refused" seems to be occurring before it hits your webserver and it's rules.

Comment: `curl -i http://localhost:80` is ok. `iptables -L` doesn;'t show any rules. Is it related to cloudflare ?

Comment: I also check nginx error log. It shows nothing related